# What is the meaning of "l" in some variables initialization - C++

Tags: c++, variables, initialization, declaration, long-integer

What is the meaning of "l" in some variable initialisations? For example:

```
#define maxpossible     (1000000000L)
double A = 1L;
double B = 999999999l;
```

Is there a difference between "L" and "l"?

Comment: It specifies a long double.

Comment: The main difference is that `l` can be mistaken for `1` whereas it is much harder to mistake `L` and `1`.  So it is generally best to use `L` rather than `l`, but semantically, there is no difference between the two suffixes.

Answer (score 5):

This is a suffix type specifier, for `A` and `B` you can read more about [floating point literals here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal). The short answer is that `L` and `l` both indicate `long double`. For `maxpossible` you can read about [integer literal here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)  and `L` indicates `long`.

**EDIT**

As Mike Seymour kindly pointed out all of the literals are `integer` literals. This just goes to show that the times when you do not sanity check your answer, you will say something wrong. A simple sanity check would have been as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid( decltype( 1L ) ).name() << std::endl ;
    std::cout << typeid( decltype( 999999999l ) ).name() << std::endl ;
    std::cout << typeid( decltype( 1000000000L ) ).name() << std::endl ;
}
```

Which gives me `l` for each one and running that through `c++filt -t` gives me `long`. What would have made the literals floating point literals? Either a:

- Digits containing a decimal point
- Digits with exponential notation, for example `4e2`

For example:

```
std::cout << typeid( decltype( .1l ) ).name() << std::endl ;
std::cout << typeid( decltype( 1e2L ) ).name() << std::endl ;
```

Which gives me `e` for both cases and running that through `c++filt -t` gives me `long double`.

Comment: Except that all three literals here are integers.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Now that I have coffee, what is sad is that you were the first one to pick that up. I still have no idea what I thought I saw when I answered(I must have mentally inserted a decimal) but clearly as I updated sanity checking would have caught it and it usually what I do. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

since These are [literal constants](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/).

The suffix `l` or `L` makes the constant be `long` or `long double`.

In your example, `maxpossible` is a `long integer`. `A` and `B` are both long doubles. But since you are declaring them as `double`, they are stored as `doubles`.